# CasperJS or PhantomJS - how to export variable in-between functions?

Tags: javascript, function, phantomjs, casperjs, var

With CasperJS or PhantomJS I want to:

**1.)** Visit 1 page and get Captcha image.

**2.)** Then decode Captcha on local server.

**3.)** Then submit the decoded Captcha results to 1. page.

**4.)** And get result (HTML).

A simple test assuming the Captcha code is `12345` to test that all values are entered and executed correctly like:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({ verbose: true, logLevel: "debug" });
var NUMBER_TO_CHECK = '356702087654321';
var DECODED_CAPTCHA = '12345';

casper.start('https://checkcoverage.apple.com/', function () {

    this.sendKeys('input#serial-number', NUMBER_TO_CHECK);
    this.sendKeys('input#captcha-input', DECODED_CAPTCHA);
    this.mouseEvent('click', '.button-label', '50%', '50%');

this.wait(1000, function () {
      this.echo('WAIT DONE');
   });
});

casper.then(function (e) {
      this.capture('logged-in.png');//print screen shot after click
});

casper.run();
```

This code snippet above gives Success result and says the given Captcha `12345` is incorrect which is true.

---

Now I need to modify this snippet so I can get the Captcha Image and process it on local server, and I have tried like:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({ verbose: true, logLevel: "debug" });
var NUMBER_TO_CHECK = '356702087654321';

casper.start('https://checkcoverage.apple.com/', function () {

    this.sendKeys('input#serial-number', NUMBER_TO_CHECK);

// Get Encoded Captcha as Var
    var captcha_encoded = casper.evaluate(function() {
        return document.getElementsByClassName('captcha-image')[0].outerHTML;
    });

// Post Encoded Captcha for decoding processing.
    casper.then(function() { this.open('http://127.0.0.1/decode_captcha.php', {
            method: 'post', data: { 'data': captcha_encoded } });
    });

// Return Decoded Captch
    casper.then(function() { var DECODED_CAPTCHA = this.getHTML('body');
        this.echo(DECODED_CAPTCHA);
        return(DECODED_CAPTCHA);        
    });


// How to Submit the Decoded Captcha result here ?
// Stuck here....
// ...
//  this.sendKeys('input#captcha-input', DECODED_CAPTCHA);
//  this.mouseEvent('click', '.button-label', '50%', '50%');


this.wait(1000, function () {
      this.echo('WAIT DONE');
   });
});

casper.then(function (e) {
      this.capture('logged-in.png');//print screen shot after click
});

casper.run();
```

With `this.echo(DECODED_CAPTCHA);` I get the Decoded Captcha result in Console logs. But `logged-in.png` shows Screenshot from Local server, not from 1. page.

---

**Question**: How can I submit the var `DECODED_CAPTCHA` result to 1. page?

Comment: Of course the screenshot will show the local page — when you open local page server you're basically abandoning the apple.com site and go to 127.0.0.1. So this is not the way to go. Now think: what other ways of I/O does PhantomJS/CasperJS have?

Answer (score 0):

This is kind a delicate question. As per official documentation there is no support for parallel browsing

[Is it possible to achieve parallel browsing using CasperJS?](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/faq.html#is-it-possible-to-achieve-parallel-browsing-using-casperjs)

And for your use case you need exactly that to keep your Captcha the same.

You can try examples posted in [this group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/casperjs/Scx4Cjqp7hE/discussion) to see if it helps you.